# Date format in XSLT List View web part

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a list with a calculated column which adds 5 days to the Created date. The date calculates correctly on the list but when displayed via XSLT it subtracts 1 day. I have found many different solutions for this problem but have but unsuccessful in implementing the fixes to my XSLT file.

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <tr class="item">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="dateCalc" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

The research I've done so far implies the issue is due to our server being in Canada using dates as `dd/mm/yyyy`. One fix I found online is: [XsltListViewWebPart and ddwrt:DateTime limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2580994)

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@*[name()= concat(current()/@Name, '.ISO8601')]),1033, 3)" />
```

I cannot figure out how to reference by column name on this. Every time I replace `@Name` for `dateCalc` I get an error:

> "Error trying to generate response. Verify your xslt."

Comment: Could it be a matter of not only what the server's date format is, but of it being in a different time zone and it adding/subtracting just enough to push it to the next day?

Comment: I would not imagine so. The server is in Quebec and I am in Eastern Ontario. Same time zone.